# How to do rank/group in python for a column?

Tags: python

I was trying to group/rank in Python like we do in SAS with Proc Rank code. The code I tried is

```
Merge_Data['FrSeg'] = Merge_Data['Frequency'].rank(method='dense').astype(int)
```

It gives me an out put with the same numbers. I would like to group into 3. 
For example, Frequency from 1-10 in rank 1, 11-20 in rank 2 and 21-above in rank 3. I have min=1 and max=68 Frequency(number orders put in- if you want to know).

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: Is this `numpy`? If so, it would be a good idea to add the `numpy` tag.

Comment: Its pandas. I found the link, but struggling to work out. I keep trying!
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rank.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be interested in [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) and [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) packages:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# dataframe to hold the list of values
df = pd.DataFrame({'FrSeg': [33, 66, 26, 5, 16, 31, 34, 10, 17, 40]})

# set the rank ranges
ranges = [0, 10, 20, 68]

# pandas.cut:
#     returns indices of half-open bins to which each value of 'FrSeg' belongs.
print df.groupby(pd.cut(df['FrSeg'], ranges)).count()
```

output:

```
          FrSeg
FrSeg          
(1, 10]       2
(10, 20]      2
(20, 68]      6
```

Comment: I tried but not the way I was looking for. I was expecting like as follows:                    
Frequency           

4                
5                
8   
2     
5      
11    
2       
32      
9      
67      
6      
12    
34     
31    
11     
17    
51     
8     
23      
56      

output: FrSeg
                1
                1
   1
    1 
      3
    2
       1
      2
      1 
      3
      1
    1
     2
    2
     1 
    1
     3
     1
      2
      3
FrSeg is a new column after applying the code.

Comment: FrSeg is a new column that group the Frequency column. I was expecting to 3 groups. I get it when I did the way I mentioned in the question above.

Comment: Sorry it's not the way you were looking for. It's difficult to read the expected output in comments as they have no formatting. Regardless, someone more experienced with your requirements will eventually provide a better solution. Until then, maybe put the method you mentioned in the comment below your question into the [Search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=) field and check other answers that have used that method

Comment: No problem. Thanks for your help any way. I never came across code with 'range'. Something I learnt new. I may have to try with conditional statement.